# Change of measure in expectation of a discrete random variable w.r.t a continuous random variable.

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem

Let us consider that I have two random variables. A discrete one, called $\alpha:\Omega\to\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and another one called $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, which is a continuous random variable. I want to compute $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\alpha|X=x\right]$. I know the probability density function of $X$, which I denote by $f_X$. I also know the conditional probability density functions $f_{X|\alpha=i}, (\forall)i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, as well as $\mathbb{P}(\alpha=i), (\forall) i\in\{1.2.3.\ldots,n\}$. With these and availing myself of the Bayes formula, I can compute the desired conditional expectation.

However, let us say that I have a way to generate realizations of X under  different measure $\mathbb{Q}$ and I also know $\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}$. Given a realization $x$ of $X$ drawn from the algorithm that simulated $X$ using measure $\mathbb{Q}$, is it correct to compute the above expectation by simply making the adjustment $x\to x\cdot\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}}\right)$ ?  If so, what is the theoretical justification?

Comment: Do you want to find $E^Q[\alpha | X]$?

Comment: @Snoop I think this is the wrong way to phrase the question. I'll probably put up a new one. Essentially I need something like Bayes formula for change of measure.